# unable to helm provision configmap with bash script

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am unable to helm provision configmap. it is setting an entry in localhost and then running binary of sonarscanner but getting error and I think it is syntax related. any hints? `line 32: could not find expected ':'` i have no clue what it is implying to fix it.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.sonarscanner.name }}-{{ .Values.sonarscanner.label }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Name }}
data:
  SONAR_HOST_URL: "-Dsonar.host.url=http://{{ .Values.sonarqube.name }}-{{ .Values.service.label }}.{{ .Values.namespace }}:{{ .Values.sonarqube.containerPort }}"
  SONAR_PROJECT_KEY: "-Dsonar.projectKey={{ .Values.sonarqube.project }}"
  CODE_PATH: "-Dsonar.sources=."
  CODE_REPO_URL: {{ .Values.repo.url }}
  CODE_REPO_NAME: {{ .Values.repo.name }}
  SONAR_PROJECT_NAME: "-Dsonar.projectName={{ .Values.sonarqube.project }}"
  RU: {{ .Values.code.httpU }}
  RT: {{ .Values.code.httpT }}
  SONAR_TOKEN: {{ .Values.code.sonarT }}
  repo_checkout.sh: |-
    #!bin/bash
    set -xe
    apt-get update && apt install dnsutils iputils-ping git curl -yq
    #Containers that fail to resolve repo url can use below step.
    repo_url=$(nslookup CODE_REPO_URL | grep Non -A 2 | grep Name | cut -d: -f2)
    repo_ip=$(nslookup CODE_REPO_URL | grep Non -A 2 | grep Address | cut -d: -f2)
    if grep $repo_url /etc/hosts; then
        echo "git dns entry exists locally"
    else
        echo "Adding dns entry for git inside container"
        echo $repo_ip $repo_url >> /etc/hosts
    fi
    cat /etc/hosts
    git clone "https://$RU:RT@$CODE_REPO_URL/r/a/$CODE_REPO_NAME" && (cd "$CODE_REPO_NAME" && mkdir -p .git/hooks && curl -Lo `git rev-parse --git-dir`/hooks/commit-msg https://$RU:RT@$CODE_REPO_URL/r/tools/hooks/commit-msg; chmod +x `git rev-parse --git-dir`/hooks/commit-msg)
```

output

```
in ./helmfile.yaml: command "/usr/local/bin/helm" exited with non-zero status:

PATH:
  /usr/local/bin/helm

ARGS:
  0: helm (4 bytes)
  1: template (8 bytes)
  2: sonarqube (9 bytes)
  3: /var/folders/nf/7ghp7kvd76n7jyzdc34kfkqm0000gp/T/tmp.X5Vhyiol (61 bytes)
  4: --namespace (11 bytes)
  5: sonarqube (9 bytes)
  6: --values (8 bytes)
  7: /var/folders/nf/7ghp7kvd76n7jyzdc34kfkqm0000gp/T/helmfile1184228953/sonarqube-sonarqube-values-c8cb44f76 (104 bytes)
  8: --values (8 bytes)
  9: /var/folders/nf/7ghp7kvd76n7jyzdc34kfkqm0000gp/T/helmfile2806006960/sonarqube-sonarqube-values-7c87b8b85f (105 bytes)
  10: --include-crds (14 bytes)
  11: --kube-version=1.13.5 (21 bytes)

ERROR:
  exit status 1

EXIT STATUS
  1

STDERR:
  Error: YAML parse error on sonarqube/templates/sonarscanner-cronjob.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 21: could not find expected ':'
  Use --debug flag to render out invalid YAML

COMBINED OUTPUT:
  Error: YAML parse error on sonarqube/templates/sonarscanner-cronjob.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 21: could not find expected ':'
  Use --debug flag to render out invalid YAML
task failed: command "helmfile --selector name=sonarqube --quiet template --include-crds --args --kube-version=1.13.5" failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: That template file looks okay at a quick glance.  Have you used the suggested `--debug` option to see what's actually being generated?  Do you know which line in the output it's complaining about?  As part of constructing a [mcve], do you know which specific lines in the template are causing problems?

Comment: I figured out that this is helm complexity of figuring out exactly what the issue is. I had referred a value map in other file and helm for unknown reason was not specifying that file in logs and rather referring to this file. 

It was other config file that was referring to a value map that did not exists in values.yaml. Let me know if I should post this as answer or close my question?

Answer (score 0):

I checked all the files under /template for line 21 as per `line 21: could not find expected ':'`and figured out that helm never complained about a configmap file where a key was referred from values on line 21.
but it never pointed out which file it was. luckily it atleast denoted ln21 and when i looked into all files, i saw that in another configmap file at ln21 there was no valuable entry.

this is how i debugged it and fixed it.